# Find records where string values are similar

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-like

I am aggregating errors in order to track total number of errors being logged.  I am currently trying to create a query that finds/groups several records that have similar value in order to record them as one error and not several individual ones.  The only difference is an id or 2, which is why they are being grouped.  The database gets injected with errors from our system via app insights and analytic stream.  I have a table that holds the "template" error that will be used to find and group those specific errors.  Not all errors being recorded need a template because they are being grouped appropriately because they are exactly the same.  When trying to use *like* to find the errors, it seems to be having a hard time with the dashes.  I am having a hard time finding info to help me with this issue.  I've tried to use the replace for removing the dashes, but that doesn't work because the errors are too long.

**Sample template:**

```
Auto Resubmit for % failed with ' Object reference not set to an instance of an object. '
```

**Sample error:**

```
Auto Resubmit for 004e9e2d-3704-4cfd-a90d-42520203df79 - 18723191 failed with ' Object reference not set to an instance of an object. '

Auto Resubmit for 0130e64e-64e6-4a23-88a4-51fba823705b - 18734821 failed with ' Object reference not set to an instance of an object. '

Auto Resubmit for 11809bf5672f4e98987119dbd06e5d78 - 17359076 failed with ' Object reference not set to an instance of an object. '
```

**Sample Query:**

```
select top 1000 * from errorTable where error like 'Auto Resubmit for % failed with '' Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Comment: Please show us your current query and let us know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Right now, I'm just trying to find the records so there is nothing special about the query.

Comment: What if you replace the `%` in your query with an id that exists in the table, does it return the corresponding record?

Comment: Break you logic into parts. You don't need to attempt to find the template value since you cannot magically replace/ignore the placeholders. You want rows that start with 'Auto Resubmit for'. And then you want to further filter those rows that contains 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. Take a stab at the logic.

Comment: Breaking up the logic does work, however, not all of the errors look like this particular one that I provided.  The ids and guids could be anywhere in the message.  (Ex. Auto Resubmit for itemid2 - 18137385 failed with ' Access Denied: userId='12602174' ')  To try and break it up, the logic would be, I think, a little complex.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing that's differing is the parameter values, you could normalize the string before storing/checking it. There are lots of utilities around that can do that. One example is the ExtractSQLTemplate function in our free SDU Tools. You don't need to use the toolkit. Just grab the code for that function as an example. You can see it here: https://youtu.be/yX5q00m_uCA

The other option is to use a full text index on the string instead. You can use functions like FREETEXTTABLE and/or FREETEXT to find similarities between the strings.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reason that you are not able to use `Template Table` is that you have basically fail the very purpose of Template by storing error in this manner.

In other word, your table are not `Normalize` nor any `relation` is define between 
2 tables.

```
Auto Resubmit for 004e9e2d-3704-4cfd-a90d-42520203df79 - 18723191 failed with 
' Object reference not set to an instance of an object. '
```

Your error table design should be like,

```
TemplateID -- id column of Template table
Module -- Name of module from where error originated
SubmoduleName-- Method name
ErrorMessage-- Original error message like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
CustomError -- Auto Resubmit for 004e9e2d-3704-4cfd-a90d-42520203df79 - 18723191 failed with
```

This way you can easily join  `Template Table` with `Error Table` using column `ErrorMessage`.

```
ErrorMessage : It should always contain original message thrown by `exception`.
```

You can customize your Error Table as per your requirement.It will take only little effort.

It would be very nice if you can store `TemplateID (FK)` in `Error` table.
All problem will vanish at once.

In short keep table in such a manner that it is easy to join them without string manipulation.

It is not clear, in what pattern `%` will be replace.

create table #Template(Templateid int identity(1,1),Template varchar(500))
insert into #Template values ('Auto Resubmit for % failed with ''Object reference not set to an instance of an object.''')

--select * from #Template

```
create table #ErrorLog(Errorid int identity(1,1),ErrorMessage varchar(500))
 insert into #ErrorLog values
('Auto Resubmit for 004e9e2d-3704-4cfd-a90d-42520203df79 - 18723191 failed with ''Object reference not set to an instance of an object.''')
,('Auto Resubmit for 0130e64e-64e6-4a23-88a4-51fba823705b - 18734821 failed with ''Object reference not set to an instance of an object.''')
,('Auto Resubmit for 11809bf5672f4e98987119dbd06e5d78 - 17359076 failed with ''Object reference not set to an instance of an object.''' )
,('Auto Resubmit for itemid2 - 18137385 failed with '' Access Denied: userId=''12602174''' )
```

Use any `split string` function to split Template table by `'%'`
and store it in `#temp` table

```
create table #temp(Errorid int identity(1,1),ErrMsg varchar(500),rownum int)

insert into #temp
select value,row_number()over(order by (Select null))rn from #Template t
cross apply(select replace(value,'failed with','')value from string_split(t.Template,'%'))ca



select t1.* from
(
select el.ErrorMessage,c.ErrMsg,c.rownum from  #ErrorLog EL 
inner join  #temp c on  el.ErrorMessage like '%' +ErrMsg+'%' and c.rownum=1
)t1
inner join  #temp c1 on  t1.ErrorMessage like '%' +ltrim(c1.ErrMsg)+'%' and c1.rownum=2


select * from #temp
drop table #Template,#ErrorLog,#temp
```

In fact,for writing near perfect query 1 need to analyze data and write as many Test cases for it.